# How to run VBA macros in all sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA, and I have a sheet which has VBA macros assigned to shapes. It works fine on the same sheet, but when I copy and paste the shapes in the next sheet or create a new shape and assign the same macro it does not work. Kindly help me. Below is the code.

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("CTSnext").Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = Black
```

Thanks for your response !!

However, Let me explain the issue.

In Sheet 1 I have 4 shapes Named
1) Cancelling the service
2) Next
3) Not interested
4) Reset

And all 3 shapes (2,3,4) will be in forecolor as white so it will be invisible.
When user clicks on "Cancelling the service" "Next" will appear (Meaning the fore color will change to black). And when "Next" is clicked "Not interested" will appear (Meaning the fore color will change to black). And when user clicks on "Reset" both "Next" & "Not interested" will turn into invisible (Meaning the fore color will change to white). Until now everything works fine.

Now i want to have a shape in Sheet 2 which says "Reset". So when user clicks on it the same function (Meaning the VBA of the "Reset" button in Sheet 1) should happen.

Below are the code.

For Cancel
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Next").Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = Black

For Next
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Notinterested").Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = Black

For Reset
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Next").Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 1
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Notinterested").Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 1

I hope i made myself clear, also i don't know to how to attach the excel file to this page so it will be helpful for you all to understand my need.

Thanks is advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your line of code refers to one specific named shape (CTSnext). You replace that by shape number if you have only one in the sheet `Shapes(0)`.
If you have several shapes on the current sheet and you want the macro to run on all shape, you can use a loop like

```
for each shp in ActiveSheet.Shapes
   shp.Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = Black
Next shp
```

Answer (score 0):

Following on from iDevlop's answer to loop through each Worksheet as well as each shape.

```
Dim wks as Worksheet
For Each wks in Me.Worksheets
    For Each shp in wks.Shapes
       shp.Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = Black
    Next shp
Next wks
```